# Android Quiz App where data needs to be stored online

Tags: android, web-services

I want to create an Android quiz app in which I want all of my data to be stored online. I have a very limited knowledge of web services and stuff like that. Please help how to proceed? Help appreciated.

Comment: Wow. That's a very broad question. Perhaps you could narrow it down a little more. Do you currently have any way of storing the data online? When you say store all the data online do you mean exclusively? Is it acceptable to cache the content on the device and download updates?.. quiz results?  A good starting point is probably going to be to look at google sample code for Android..

Comment: Hi James, basically I want to store Questions as well as answers to the questions, online. I have no idea how to do that. I just want to know how to start? I can create a basic android quiz app but in order to make decrease the size of the application I believe it will be good if I store all the data(questions+answers+descriptions) online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about using :

1. google app engine for example to save data in cloud     https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial
2. Parse http://parse.com , StackMob...(has stoped new subscription)

hope this help,